# Путь Back-end разработчика

Tags: php, backend

Хотел бы пойти в сторону back-end программирования. Посмотрел, какой лучше язык выбрать, и остановился на php. Хотелось бы попросить помощи по junior позиции: что для начала нужно знать и учить в последовательности.

На данный момент знаю HTML/CSS/Основы JS, boostrap, flexbox, sass.
Буду очень благодарен за помощь.

Comment: вопрос следует закрыть так как он слишком общий

Comment: Можно отсюда программу обучения взять: https://htmlacademy.ru/intensive/php#program

Answer (score 1):

Как back-end в первую очередь вы должны хорошо владеть языком запросов SQL, уметь проектировать базы данных.

Но судя по вашему опыту, могу предположить что вам не помешает изучить основные структуры данных, такие как связанные списки, деревья. И посидеть над изучением основных алгоритмов.

Помимо этого вы должны хорошо понимать ООП и знать основные [паттерны проектирования](https://refactoring.guru/ru/design-patterns).

Так же не помешает изучить систему контроля версий, например [git](https://githowto.com/ru).